# How to call uninstall.php?

Tags: wordpress

I have created my plugin and now I am creating **uninstall.php** file for uninstall my plugin.

This is my code of *uninstall.php*

```
  if(!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN'))
    exit ();

  *** here I am droping my table and options...
```

I don't know how to call *uninstall.php*? From where to call it to uninstall my plugin?

I know `register_uninstall_hook()` but when it get triggered?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ShivanRaptor off topic?? i tagged it to wrodpress only then also off topic..

Comment: Not really a programming question, but a WordPress library usage question. Read the WordPress SE's FAQ.

Comment: Registers the uninstall hook will be called when the user clicks on the uninstall link that calls for the plugin to uninstall itself.

Comment: @BhumiShah from where i find uninstall link for that particular plugin? how to create uninstall link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall hook and uninstall.php file are two alternate ways to implement uninstall functionality, they are independent of each other.

When **uninstall_plugin()** is called it checks for uninstall.php or hook (in this order).

So if you are using file approach there is nothing special you need to do to call it. WordPress looks it's up by name and runs on uninstall natively.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php register_uninstall_hook($file, $callback) ?>
```

**You are looking for uninstall hook**

**refer here for more [Uninstall hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook)**

***"Registers the uninstall hook that will be called when the user clicks on the uninstall link that calls for the plugin to uninstall itself. The link won't be active unless the plugin hooks into the action"*** -- **From codex**