# wordpress: wp_delete_post in uninstall.php doesn't delete my custom posts

Tags: wordpress

Hi :) I'm working on my first plugin..
I have registered my custom post type, with its meta boxes and its taxonomy ..
everything seems to work fine except that when I uninstall the plugin, the function in my uninstall.php doesn't delete posts.

Here my **uninstall.php**

```
     // If uninstall not called from WordPress, then exit.
     if ( ! defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
        exit;
     }

     global $wpdb;

     // Delete All Custom Type Posts
     $posts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'my-custom-post', // $post_type
        'post_status' => 'any' ) );

     foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true );
     }
```

I've looked everywhere - even inside other plugins - and it seems that this is the right way to do it ...someone can tell me why it doesn't work? or even if there is some other way?

Comment: your code looks ok, how do you call the uninstall.php?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
I thought it was enough to put uninstall.php in the root of the plugin..

I read this thing somewhere and they say it here too:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900769/how-to-call-uninstall-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900769/how-to-call-uninstall-php)

But it still doesn't work for me ... any other ideas?

Comment: I tested your code and works fine. Are you sure about the post type name? Add the following after your `get_posts` to make sure it's working: `wp_die( sprintf( '<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $posts, true ) ) );`

Comment: Hi, brasofilo! thanks for your suggestion and sorry it took me a while to respond...
I tried your code and it returns an empty array ... I wonder why?
The `$post_type` is correct and if I try the same function attached to the deactivation hook it works perfectly... maybe I need to do a check for the multisite network?

I try to do it maybe it works... in the meantime do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

From the codex,

`register_uninstall_hook` registers the uninstall hook that will be called when the user clicks on the uninstall link that calls for the plugin to uninstall itself.

```
register_uninstall_hook($file, $callback)
```

[check this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have investigated a bit...
reading here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98965/get-posts-from-sites-in-multisite

and here:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979

Then I have temporarily replaced get_posts() with a new WP_Query(), same arguments, and then I printed the query in this way:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'my-custom-post',
    'post_status' => 'any'
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

wp_die( sprintf( '<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $posts->request, true ) ) );
```

with this result:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  _wpposts.ID FROM _wpposts  WHERE 1=1  AND _wpposts.post_type = 'my-custom-post' AND (_wpposts.post_status = 'publish' OR _wpposts.post_status = 'future' OR _wpposts.post_status = 'draft' OR _wpposts.post_status = 'pending' OR _wpposts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY _wpposts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I think the problem here is that the plugin is active on a multisite network but only in one of that sites (with ID 2) there are posts with my $post_type...
so I tried to make a loop through the blogs using `switch_to_blog()` with this function:

```
function my_uninstall_plugin() {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( function_exists( 'is_multisite' ) && is_multisite() ) {
        $blog_sql = "SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE archived = '0' AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0'";
        $blog_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $blog_sql );

        if ( $blog_ids ) {
            foreach ( $blog_ids as $blog_id ) {
                switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

                 global $post;
                 $args = array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_type'   => 'un-custom-post',
                    'post_status' => 'any'
                );
                $blog_posts = get_posts( $args );
                if($blog_posts) {
                    foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post) {
                        wp_delete_post( $blog_post->ID, true );
                    }
                }
            }
            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }
}
```

And now it seems to work...
thanks to  Vidhu Nair and brasofilo for your help! :)